# Biblatex entry to cite an article with a single author followed by "et al"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using `biblatex` and I would like to cite [this article](http://ligo.org/detections/GW170817/paper/GW170817-PRLpublished.pdf). As you can see, the article has lots of authors, but I would like to mention the list of authors as it appers in the article: as “B. P. Abbott *et al.*”. How can I do that? If I put `author="B. P. Abbott \textit{et al.}"` in the `.bib` file, the presence of the `et al.` will wreck the sorting order.

Comment: Give enough authors to trigger "et al." automatically. This of course depends on your setup, so please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @samcarter Thank you. That solved my problem. I did not even try that, bacause I thought that the *et al.* would be appended only after the third author. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Possibility one: just use the full author list, it is available as `.bib` file from the journal website https://journals.aps.org/prl/export/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.161101?type=bibtex&download=true
- Possibility two: For most cases you will not notice any difference between giving the full author list and a truncated one, as long as it contains enough authors to trigger "et al." (the specific number may vary with the style you use). To mark in your `.bib` file that the list is truncated you could conclude it with `and others`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{PhysRevLett.119.161101,
  title = {GW170817: Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Neutron Star Inspiral},
  author = {Abbott, B. P. and Abbott, R. and Abbott, T. D. and Acernese, F. and Ackley, K. and Adams, C. and Adams, T. and Addesso, P. and Adhikari, R. X. and Adya, V. B. and Affeldt, C. and Afrough, M. and Agarwal, B. and Agathos, M. and Agatsuma, K. and others},
  collaboration = {LIGO Scientific Collaboration and Virgo Collaboration},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {119},
  issue = {16},
  pages = {161101},
  numpages = {18},
  year = {2017},
  month = {Oct},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.161101},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.161101}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{PhysRevLett.119.161101}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: samcarter, don't you think it would be worth some comment on biblatex's options like `maxnames` or `maxcitenames`, and `maxbibnames`?

Comment: @gusbrs Not without knowing how the OP uses biblatex. That's why I asked for a MWE.

Comment: The only correct way to go about using possibility two is `and others` that is a recognised keyword, `and et al.` just pretends that the last author is called `et al.`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for you comment, I removed the offending sentence.

Comment: That is not to say that no one has thought about `and et al.`: http://smbc-comics.com/comic/citations-needed

Comment: @moewe :) I wonder if this author counts towards ones Erdős number